# Connect ASP.NET WebSite to SQL Database

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, ado.net, database-connection

I am currently trying to establish a connection between an ASP.NET web site project and a Database built by SQL Server 2008 R2.

The way I am required to do so is to use the `connectionString` from the `Web.config` page, but I have no idea what value to give it or how to establish a connection using said value. (Using C#)

Any help would be appreciated, as I found next to no information about the subject.

Here is the (default) value that is currently in the `Web.config` page:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="ApplicationServices" connectionString="data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

Comment: This may be useful to you...Its a trick for creating Connection strings  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954029/how-to-use-sqlconnect-or-sqldriverconnect/3954073#3954073

Comment: "I found next to no information about the subject" - there are over 5000 hits on SO alone for 'connectionstring'!!!

Comment: @KreepN I did, but I am not sure about how proper my connection string is... this is all I put in it, and it works: `Server=loca5lhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=levidb`.

Comment: Correct. When you're connection to a local DB, the string itself doesn't require much configuring. When you're connection to a SQL server instance on another machine is when it seems to look different and require more fields.

Comment: Here's my local one which I snagged from visual studio: Data Source=J\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=MyCatalog;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=*****;Password=***********

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Configuration Manager:

```
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;

string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;

using(SqlConnection SqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString));
```

//The rest is here to show you how this connection would be used. But the code above this comment is all you really asked for, which is how to connect.

```
{

   SqlDataAdapter SqlDataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
   SqlCommand SqlCommand = new SqlCommand();

   SqlConnection.Open();
   SqlCommand.CommandText = "select * from table";
   SqlCommand.Connection = SqlConnection;
   SqlDataReader dr = SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);

}
```

Comment: If en exception will occur before a reader execution, the connection will not be closed. Thus I recommend to use `using` block.

Comment: Personal preference, as he could be using it in a try-catch block. I'd agree, however, and will make sure I notate that accordingly.

Comment: This does show me how to retrieve the connection string, so that part is pretty much answered for me. What to write in the `Web.config` file is another matter. Currently I simply did this: `Server=localhost;Trusted_Connection=yes;Database=mydb` and it works, but it seems far off from the default value that is in there.

Answer (score 0):

This article about [Connect to SQL Server Using SQL Authentication in ASP.NET](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648340.aspx) will probably give you a better idea of what need to be done.

As a pre check, just check if your `mssqlserver` services are running.

Comment: Problem is, I'm using ASP.Net 4 and I don't know how applicable information about ASP.Net 2 is.

Answer (score 0):

```
string connectionString =  ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings[connectionStringName].ConnectionString;

using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (SqlCommand command = connection.CreateCommand())
{
    command.CommandText = commandText;

    // command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@param", value);

    connection.Open();
    command.ExecuteNonQuery(); // or command.ExecuteScalar() or command.ExecuteRader()
}
```