# How do I write SQL connection string?

Tags: asp.net, sql, connection

I have this as my connection string property:

```
Data Source="c:\users\perdanny\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\WebApplication1\WebApplication1\App_Data\Users.sdf"
```

Now, how should I write it in my code:

```
sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(???);
```

Comment: Similar question asked before: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8014901/connect-asp-net-website-to-sql-database

Comment: If you've got an sdf file rather than a SQL Server database, chances are you want `SQLCeConnection` rather than `SQLConnection`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

use ConfigurationManager and

look at below code line:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ApplicationServices"].ConnectionString;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
string strConnection = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["Name of connection string key"].ConnectionString;  

// Or, for a quick test you could also use
// string strConnection = "Data Source = c:\\users\\perdanny\\documents\\visual studio 2012\\Projects\\WebApplication1\\WebApplication1\\App_Data\\Users.sdf"     

  using (var conn = new SqlCeConnection(string.Format("Data Source={0}", strConnection)))
  {
     conn.Open();

     try
     {
         System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand cmd = System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeCommand;
         cmd.CommandType = System.Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure;
         cmd.CommandText = "Your sql stored proc name";
         cmd.Connection = conn ;
         cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();     
     }
     catch (SqlCeException)
     {
         throw;
     }
     finally
     {
         if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open) conn.Close();
     }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

string connStr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["connectionString"].ToString();

```
<add name="connectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=dbsql;User ID=hello;Password=hello"
      providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```